# Can't figure out a proper way to do a loop that loops until input is valid

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, joptionpane

I'm still learning java programming so forgive my lack of knowledge.
It probably is the most simplest thing ever, but I just can't for the life of me figure out a better way to have the *checkTaskDescription* method loop until the user input description is below the character limit. So far this is the only way I've been able to do it but it clearly repeats the input dialog twice.

This is the part that executes it

```
 do{
     checkTaskDescription();
    }
       while (checkTaskDescription() == false);
```

This is the checkTaskDescription method that is being executed:

```
public boolean checkTaskDescription() {
        taskDesc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a short description of the task");
        if (taskDesc.length() > 50) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a task description of less than 50 characters.", "ERROR",3);
            taskDesc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a short description of the task");
            return false;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Task successfully captured.");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Tried with `do-while`?

Comment: do-while? @SayanBhattacharya

Comment: instead of using `while` loop use `do-while` loop. refer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-do-while-loop-with-examples/)

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya Ok, i will try

Comment: Don't use a loop. Instead add a PropertyListener to the option pane that will allow you to validate the data entered before closing the option panel Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Stop Automatic Dialog Closing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup)

Comment: @camickr I have to use a loop, its for a project.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya I have updated the question using your suggestion but it still repeats the input dialog

Comment: Walk through your code. 1st it enters the "do" block. It calls "checkTaskDescription()", and does nothing with the return value. Then it goes to the conditional of your "while" and ... calls "checkTaskDescription()". You need to do something with the return value of your first "checkTaskDescription";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the results of your method call.

```java
boolean ready = false;

do{

    ready = checkTaskDescription();

} while ( ! ready );
```

That will enter the do block, assign ready to the return value of checkTaskDescription(), then check if it is false. If it is false, it will continue to loop, until it is true.

Your checkTaskDescription is also broken. If you fail the first time, it will show the dialog again, then **always return false**.

```
public boolean checkTaskDescription() {
        taskDesc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a short description of the task");
        if (taskDesc.length() > 50) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a task description of less than 50 characters.");
            return false;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Task successfully captured.");
        return true;
    }
```

I updated the method so it would "work" when there is a failed input, it will show an error message, then loop and show the dialog again. This is why you should validate the data from the dialog, and not open the dialog in the loop.

Comment: So you need to give it a boolean to start with?

Comment: @Enzie that isn't really the point. The point is you need to use the return value of your method call. You could just have `while( ! checkTaskDescription() ){}`.

Comment: So I had to use the value that was returned by the checkTaskDescription boolean then It would have been able to actually run

Comment: regarding your recent edit @matt, Yes that is exactly what is happening

Comment: @Enzie I've added an updated version of your method. I hope you're getting a bit of a feel for stepping through the program in your mind and predicting what should happen.

Comment: yea, I'm getting there, its really hard trying to do so much in your head at once XD, thanks alot

Comment: Yes it takes a bit of getting used to. When it works, go back and see if you can step through line by line and follow the program flow. Debuggers can help too.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier if you do something like this

```
public String getTaskDescription() {
    String taskDescription = "";
    do {
        taskDescription = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a short description of the task");
    }
    while (taskDescription.length() > 50);

    return taskDescription;
}
```

When you design your methods, try to make them as self-contained as possible. Now you return a flag and rely on a caller method to call it again in case the input isn't valid.

Comment: Is this replacing the checkTaskDescription or adding a new one?

Comment: Yes replaces the whole thing. You need to obtain the task at the end right?

Comment: Okay well, the checkTaskDescription is required to be a boolean.

Comment: taskDescription is a field they don't need to return it.